# C#, DirectShow -- video was capturing to file -- live view

Tags: c#, video, directshow, video-capture

I must write a simple program in C# to show on the screen video which was capturing from external card which is named: iEi HDC-304E. It has 4 hdmi inputs and I've got 4 cameras which are streaming video via hdmi. I'm working on Windows 7 and Visual Studio.

I have got lib for this card and it is capturing video from hdmi input to a mpg file. I cannot access to live stream, exactly what I mean: I cannot to access FileStream or something like that to get byte data in the program. I wonder if I can open the file which was create by the library and it show on the screen, but I don't know how to do this. I wanted to do before, but I had got exception about: cannot play this file. Exception: System.Runtime.InteropSercives.COMException.

And my another question is that delay show it won't be to big ?

Any one has the similar problem ? 
Any hint will be appreciate.

Comment: You have tagged this with directshow. Does that mean your capture card has proper directshow drivers?

Comment: Yes, I think so. In SDK specification is writed: The DumpFile.dll and PushFileSource.dll are filters of DirectShow, but I don't know how to use it properly. Now my program saving mpg file to a hard drive and then I get FileStream from the specify url where was created the file. But I think is a bad idea and when I want to show live preview, it'll be so much delay from real time. What do you think about that ?

Comment: You can try [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) first to check if you can access the capture device and render it to screen directly. If that is working, it would be possible to create more advanced graphs which simultaneously capture to file and show a preview.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tried with this program earlier, but I don't know what I suppose to add to it. I tried add DumpFile and PushFileSource, but I didn't work properly. I cannot connect PushFileSource to Video renderer. If you can look for [SDK documentaton](https://files.secureserver.net/0scho64rs5zUgM) and on the 40's page there is a graph, which represent how to suppose work Maybe you find  some solution for my problem. I really need it ;-)

Comment: For testing you can use something like [VH Screen Capture Driver](http://www.splitmedialabs.com/media-toolkits/vh-video-sdk/vh-screen-capture) because that includes a directshow driver for sure. In Graphstudio select Graph-Insert Filter, choose video capture sources, for example VHSrcCap to test, press insert and ok without specifying a filename. Right click on the capture output pin and select render. Run the graph with the play button in the toolbar. You capture card should work the same way, possibly you have to select "WDM streaming capture devices" instead of "video capture sources".

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I've got in my video capture sources my capture card. I add to surface the block, which look like [this](http://snag.gy/bHfpU.jpg). I've done like in WDM, right click and click render pin, but program crashed every time I do this. Help me, please.